# Proving the independence of two terms as an implication of a fact

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,...,X_i$ be i.i.d normal random variables. I want to show that $(X_1-\frac{1}{n}\sum_iX_i, ..., X_n - \frac{1}{n} \sum_i X_i)$ and $\sum_i X_i$ are independent, as the implication of the fact that {$(x_1,...,x_n)\in R^n | \sum_i x_i = 0$} and {$\lambda(1,...,1)| \lambda \in R$} are orthogonal vector subspaces of $R^n$.

I have no idea how to do this. I mean I understand that the $1/n\sum_i X_i$ is the normalised sum or in other terms the estimation of each random variable. But what does it have to do?

Comment: Random vectors "Orthogonality" depends on the underlying distribution. The orthogonality of non-random subspaces in general doesn't guarantee the random counterparts, except for the normal distribution case.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Yes, indeed. I edited the question. Can you prove it?

Comment: Start with determining the joint distribution of $\xi = (X_1 - \bar{X}, \ldots, X_n - \bar{X})$ and $\eta = \sum X_i$. The fact you listed is indeed helpful as an aftermath interpretation, but as a rigor proof, you should verify that $f(\xi, \eta) = f(\xi)f(\eta)$ by citing normal distribution properties.

Comment: Yeah, that direction is simple. I'm looking for the other way. So assume that we have that {$(x_1,...,x_n)\in R^n | \sum_i x_i = 0$} and {$\lambda(1,...,1)| \lambda \in R$} are orthogonal vector subspaces of $R^n$. How can you use this to imply the intended independence

Comment: You probably would need the Cramer-Wold device: i.e., two random vectors are independent if and only if all their linear combinations (as random variables) are independent. But again, setting up the stage so that the fact you cited can be directly applicable is lengthy. Again, as I stated, it's better to just use it as a good interpretation instead of a rigorous proof.

Comment: @Zhanxiong, Ok, Do you know where I can get the lengthy proof?

Comment: Check the book *The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models*, Chapter 3. Intuitively (a sketch of the proof): let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $M = \text{span}(e)$, where $e = (1, \ldots, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then $\bar{X}e = P_M(\mathbf{X})$ and $\mathbf{X} - \bar{X}e = P_{M^\perp}(\mathbf{X})$. Since $M$ and $M^\perp$ are orthogonal (as you observed), then according to Theorem 8.2 in that book you can claim $\bar{X}e$ and $\mathbf{X} - \bar{X}e$ are independent. Here "$P_M$" refers to the orthogonal projection operator in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might give you a "middle" solution between the pure probability density calculation and the lengthy geometric proof, by a little matrix algebra, which in fact implicitly uses the fact you stated in the question.

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)^T$, $e = (1, \ldots, 1)^T$ be column vectors, then

\begin{align*}
\begin{pmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix} := 
\begin{pmatrix} \mathbf{X} - \bar{X} \\ \bar{X} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
I_{(n)} - \frac{1}{n}ee^T \\
\frac{1}{n}e^T \end{pmatrix}\mathbf{X}, 
\end{align*}

Since
$\mathbf{X}$ are jointly normal and $(\xi^T, \eta)^T$ is a linear transformation of it, $(\xi^T, \eta)^T$ are jointly normal. Therefore $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent if and only if they
are uncorrelated, i.e., $\mathrm{Cov}(\xi, \eta) = 0$.

Indeed,
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Cov}(\xi, \eta) = \frac{1}{n}\left(I_{(n)} - \frac{1}{n}ee^T\right)\mathrm{Cov}(X)e 
= \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2(e - n^{-1}ee^Te) = 0. 
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also found Theorem 1 of https://jekyll.math.byuh.edu/courses/m321/handouts/mean_var_indep.pdf   which proves similar thing to mine.